# calculate the mean of one row according it's label

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

calculate the mean of the values in one row according it's label:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
B = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1, 1]

Result = pd.DataFrame(data=[A, B])
```

I want the output is: 0->3; 1-> 7.8

pandas has the groupby function, but I don't know how to implement this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is simple `groupby` problem ...

```
Result=Result.T
Result.groupby(Result[1])[0].mean()
Out[372]: 
1
0    3
1    8
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it sounds like you want to label the index:

```
In [11]: Result = pd.DataFrame(data=[A, B], index=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: Result
Out[12]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9
A  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
B  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1
```

If the index was unique you wouldn't have to do any groupby, just take the mean of each row (that's the axis=1):

```
In [13]: Result.mean(axis=1)
Out[13]:
A    5.5
B    0.5
dtype: float64
```

However, if you had multiple rows with the same label, then you'd need to groupby:

```
In [21]: Result2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[A, A, B], index=['A', 'A', 'B'])

In [22]: Result2.mean(axis=1)
Out[22]:
A    5.5
A    5.5
B    0.5
dtype: float64
```

Note: the duplicate rows (that happen to have the same mean as I lazily used the same row contents), in general we'd want to take the mean of those means:

```
In [23]: Result2.mean(axis=1).groupby(level=0).mean()
Out[23]:
A    5.5
B    0.5
dtype: float64
```

*Note: `.groupby(level=0)` groups the rows which have the same index label.*

Answer (score 0):

You're making it difficult on yourself by constructing the dataframe in such a way as to put the things you want to take the mean of and the things you want to be your labels as different rows.

**Option 1**
`groubpy`
This deals with the data presented in the dataframe `Result`

```
Result.loc[0].groupby(Result.loc[1]).mean()

1
0    3
1    8
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 2**
Overkill using `np.bincount` and because your grouping values are `0` and `1`.  I'd have a solution even if they weren't but it makes it simpler.
I wanted to use the raw lists `A` and `B`

```
pd.Series(np.bincount(B, A) / np.bincount(B))

0    3.0
1    8.0
dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 3**
Construct a series instead of a dataframe.
Again using raw lists `A` and `B`

```
pd.Series(A, B).mean(level=0)

0    3
1    8
dtype: int64
```